# Meeting Setup/Hold Time according to time analysis

Tags: fpga, interface, high-speed

I am trying to interface an IC with an FPGA. Both the IC & FPGA run at 66 MHz with no clock skew between them and the propagation delay of the data lines is negligible, since the length of the PCB traces that connect the 2 chips is very short.

The IC has a setup time 1 ns and hold time 4.8 ns, while the sampling of the data is performed at the rising edge of the clock.

According to the I/O Timing Analysis report of the FPGA software, which is created after the Place & Route so I assume is the absolute final report, I have a Clock to Output delay of around 10 ns.

If the FPGA outputs data at the rising edge with the system clock period being 15 ns and the clock-to-output delay 10 ns, new data have arrive 3 ns before the required setup time so I respect the setup time, which is 1 ns. At the same time, in the next cycle, since the clock to output is 10 ns, the new data will become available after 10 ns, so I have respected the hold time as well, which is 4.8 ns.

Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

FPGA is MachXO2 by Lattice (TQFP-144) while the IC in question is FT601 by FTDI, which is USB 3.0 to FIFO Bridge. Since clock-to-out is 10 ns, and the next output will become available when the rising edge comes, I assume to have a hold time of 10 ns (5 ns before the rising edge arrives plus 10 ns after the rising edge, which is the clock-to-output delay, totaling 15 ns).

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more information:
- What kind of IC are you driving with which FPGA? What's the general function of the circuit?
- How long does the FPGA hold the output signal you're trying to send to/sample with the IC?
A sketch of your planned timing diagram could be helpful too.

Comment: @georgjz Added the requested information.

Comment: Can you give a more general description of your circuit and maybe a schematic? Your basic reasoning about timing could be right, but it's hard to tell without seeing all the other control signals. If you could provide a timing diagram, or better a print out of a scope/logic probe of your signals, that'd be helpful.

Comment: 10ns Tco seems a bit long for a MACHXO2 chip.  Is the clock generated externally?  Are you using the internal PLL?  In general it is marginal to depend on a maximum Tco to meet a hold time, since the typical delay can be much less than the maximum.  In your case, since the required hold time is less than half of the max Tco, you are probably OK.  You can get an idea of how close the timing is by looking at the actual Tco with a scope.

Comment: @georgjz I don't have the actual circuit yet, it is fabricated as we speak. I am currently writing the controller in advance so I have it ready when it arrives.

Comment: @crj11 The clock is provided as input, externally, and is connected in one of the dedicated primary clock pads. According to Lattice Diamond PAR and I/O Timing Analysis, my Tco is minimum 9 ns and maximum 11 ns, that's why I wrote around 10 ns in the original question. You are right that is a bit long for the MachXO2, but this is due to the fact that there is some combinational logic proceeding the output and, also, because the FT601 has many data/control lines (around 40), so the final routing is kinda perplexed in the TQFP-144 version.

Comment: @Manos If Diamond says you have a minimum of 8ns, you should be fine on the hold time.  The minimum of the Tco plus the Tpd on the combi logic appear to provide all the hold time that you need.  If you ever need to adjust the phase in a similar but less forgiving situation, you can use the internal PLL to do fine adjustment of an internal clock versus the external clock to shift the setup and hold times.

Comment: @crj11 Thanks for your answer. You could write it as a proper answer to the question so I can accept it.